# How can i insert 2 new rows extraction from a query in query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have to change a raw, and split it, but i dont figure it out how.

```
SELECT A.QADAte, A.ProcessorType, A.ASDType ,A.Threshold, A.Accuracy, A.Accept, A.ItemsQty, C.Accuracy Accuracy01, C.Accept Accept01, C.ItemsQty ItemsQty01, D.Accuracy Accuracy07,
D.Accept Accept07, D.ItemsQty ItemsQty07, E.Accuracy Accuracy30, E.Accept Accept30, E.ItemsQty ItemsQty30
from `serv.dbo.accuracies` A inner join
(SELECT ProcessorType, max(QADate) maxQADate FROM `serv.dbo.accuracies` group by ProcessorType)
B ON A.QADate = B.maxQADate and A.ProcessorType = B.ProcessorType and A.SkipNulls = true and A.ASDType = '%' and A.Days=6
left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` C ON C.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and C.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and C.ASDType = '%' and C.SkipNulls = true and C.Days=6
left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` D ON D.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -7 DAY) and D.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and D.ASDType = '%' and D.SkipNulls = true and D.Days=6
left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` E ON E.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -30 DAY) and E.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and E.ASDType = '%' and E.SkipNulls = true and E.Days=6
```

And the result is this

[image]

I have to extract the F06 raw and get him in 2 different raws where ASDType is other than '%'. I must keep the rest of the datas as they are in the table.

Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in tableau aswell but since you are using query directly, its better to link multiple queries and get the result set.

To the extent I understand to get the saperate row, you need to create a one more query 
and do a union for both queries. For second query take only `F06` and `ASDType <> '%'`as filter check second query I have added it

```sql
    SELECT A.QADAte, A.ProcessorType, A.ASDType ,A.Threshold, A.Accuracy, A.Accept, A.ItemsQty, C.Accuracy Accuracy01, C.Accept Accept01, C.ItemsQty ItemsQty01, D.Accuracy Accuracy07,
    D.Accept Accept07, D.ItemsQty ItemsQty07, E.Accuracy Accuracy30, E.Accept Accept30, E.ItemsQty ItemsQty30
    from `serv.dbo.accuracies` A inner join
    (SELECT ProcessorType, max(QADate) maxQADate FROM `serv.dbo.accuracies` group by ProcessorType)
    B ON A.QADate = B.maxQADate and A.ProcessorType = B.ProcessorType and A.SkipNulls = true and A.ASDType = '%' and A.Days=6
    left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` C ON C.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and C.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and C.ASDType = '%' and C.SkipNulls = true and C.Days=6
    left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` D ON D.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -7 DAY) and D.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and D.ASDType = '%' and D.SkipNulls = true and D.Days=6
    left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` E ON E.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -30 DAY) and E.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and E.ASDType = '%' and E.SkipNulls = true and E.Days=6

UNION

    SELECT A.QADAte, A.ProcessorType, A.ASDType ,A.Threshold, A.Accuracy, A.Accept, A.ItemsQty, C.Accuracy Accuracy01, C.Accept Accept01, C.ItemsQty ItemsQty01, D.Accuracy Accuracy07,
    D.Accept Accept07, D.ItemsQty ItemsQty07, E.Accuracy Accuracy30, E.Accept Accept30, E.ItemsQty ItemsQty30
    from `serv.dbo.accuracies` A inner join
    (SELECT ProcessorType, max(QADate) maxQADate FROM `serv.dbo.accuracies` group by ProcessorType)
    B ON A.QADate = B.maxQADate and A.ProcessorType = B.ProcessorType and A.SkipNulls = true and A.ASDType = '%' and A.Days=6
    left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` C ON C.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -1 DAY) and C.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and C.ASDType <> '%' and C.SkipNulls = true and C.Days=6 and B.ProcessorType = 'F06'
    left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` D ON D.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -7 DAY) and D.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and D.ASDType = '%' and D.SkipNulls = true and D.Days=6
    left join `serv.dbo.accuracies` E ON E.QADate=DATE_ADD(A.QADate, INTERVAL -30 DAY) and E.ProcessorType = A.ProcessorType and E.ASDType = '%' and E.SkipNulls = true and E.Days=6
```